# distinct records sum when joining different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

**Table : O**

```
ID  Date
1   2016-01-10
2   2016-01-10
3   2016-01-11
```

**Table : OD**

```
ODI   ID     Quantity
1     1        1 
2     1        2
3     2        1
4     3        1
```

**Table: OH**

```
OHI   ID
1     1         
2     2       
3     1        
4     3
```

I have three table O,OD,OH. I need to join these three table and get the sum of quantity For each day.
Tried

```
SELECT O.date,SUM(od.Quantity),group_concat(OHI) FROM O
INNER JOIN OD ON OD.ID = O.ID
INNER JOIN OH ON OH.ID = O.ID
GROUP BY O.date;
```

But the resulting quantity sum was different due to joining the OH Table.Now How do i get the proper Sum.

**Expected Result :**

```
Date   SUM(od.Quantity)
2016-01-10        4       
2016-01-10        1
```

Sorry For Change In The Question.

Comment: Why do you want to join with `OH` table?

Comment: have some other data in that table related to O table...So to get those data I need to join

Comment: @Manojhebbani If some other data you need from OH table, kindly mention those records in sample too.

Comment: Question was little changed. Reply for that.

Comment: I gave you an answer below.  Actually, multiple did.

Comment: But I changed the question.you replied for the previous one.

Comment: @Manojhebbani When I checked your previous questions, you have not accepted any answer for any of the question. Does none of those answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `join` OH table, this can be done with below query:

```
SELECT O.ID,SUM(od.Quantity) FROM O
INNER JOIN OD ON OD.ID = O.ID
GROUP BY O.ID;
```

Comment: I need a join to OH Table...Because some other data am selecting from the OH table...Sorry i didn't mention that in the table...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join with the OH table.

```
select O.ID, SUM(OD.Quantity) total_qty
from O inner join OD
on O.ID = OD.ID
group by O.ID;
```

If you need join with OH, then do it after aggregation.

```
select *
from OH inner join (
    select O.ID, SUM(OD.Quantity) total_qty
    from O inner join OD
    on O.ID = OD.ID
    group by O.ID
) t on t.ID = OH.ID;
```

Comment: I need a join to OH Table...Because some other data am selecting from the OH table...Sorry i didn't mention that in the query and table structure..

Comment: Question was little changed. Reply for that.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate over the `OD` table first in a subquery, then join this to the other two tables:

```
SELECT t1.Date,
       t2.Quantity,
       t3.OHI   -- and possibly other columns from OH
FROM O t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM OD
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN OH t3
    ON t1.ID = t3.ID
```